# disable submit button until all form inputs have a value in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I would like to disable the form submit button until all inputs have a value in them. My view has these inputs:

```
  <%= form_for @item, html: { enctype: "multipart/form-data", id: "upload-data" } do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
```

I then run this `validate()` function with every `keyup` event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  validate();
  $('input').on('keyup', validate);
});

function validate() {
  var input = $('input');
  var isValid = false;
  $.each(input, function(k, v) {
    if (v.type != "submit") {
      isValid = (k == 0) ?
        v.value ? true : false : isValid && v.value ? true : false;
    }
    if (isValid) {
      $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
    }
  });
}
```

Though the same code works [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/1qyLxemb/) it does not work in my Rails view. It stays disabled. What am I overlooking?

Comment: maybe because of turbolinks in rails you just  can't just copy paste the javascript you need to adapt it into turbolinks script and syntax try this
`$(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', function() {});` instead `$(document).ready(function() {});`

Comment: could u add more detail like where did you put the javascript, and the html page source?

Comment: the javascript is in the old app/assets/javascript directory for Rails 5.2.4, and the page source is in app/views/items/new

Comment: Why not just use HTML5 validations? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

Answer (score 1):

maybe because turbolinks, in rails you can't just copy paste the javascript you need to adapt it into turbolinks script and syntax

you could try to change your script from

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

into

```
$(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', function() {

})
```

Comment: still no go. any idea how i could troubleshoot this?

Comment: did the script loaded? you can try it by putting console.log("loaded") inside the bracket

Comment: the script is definitely loading, the problem is that it fires once when the page loads, and then never fires again